# Database concurrency exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency

we're working on a database for our study project, and we've got unexpected error while adding data to a table.

```
using (var ctx = new BazyDanychContext())
{
    Osoba tmpTask = new Osoba { Imie = ImieLbl.Text, Nazwisko = NazwiskoLbl.Text, Telefon = TelefonLbl.Text, Adres = AdresLbl.Text, Mail = MailLbl.Text, IloscTransakcji = Int32.Parse(IloscLbl.Text), Typ = TypList.Text };
    ctx.Osoba.Add(tmpTask);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

We also tried:

- To add new records using ExecuteSqlCommand, which worked just fine

  ```
  ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Osoba VALUES('0','jan','nowak', '222222', 'adres', 'mail', '2', 'osoba')");
  ```
- Using `ctx.Entry(tmpTask).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;` (and also `.Modified`)
- Typing the values manually (like in the ExecuteSqlCommand line)

No matter what we do, `ctx.SaveChanges()` gives us

```
OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0).
```

Our classes:

```
namespace BazyDanych
{ 
    public class BazyDanychContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public BazyDanychContext() : base("ProjektBD")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new SQLdb());
        }

        public DbSet<Osoba> Osoba { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace BazyDanych
{
    public class Osoba
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Imie { get; set; }
        public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
        public string Telefon { get; set; }
        public string Adres { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public int IloscTransakcji { get; set; }
        public string Typ { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Imie: " + Imie + "\t Nazwisko: " + Nazwisko + "\t ID: " + ID.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Database table's structure looks like:

```
ID (int, null)
Imie (text, null)
Nazwisko (text, null)
Telefon (text, null)
Adres (text, null)
Mail (text, null)
IloscTransakcji (int, null)
Typ (text, null)
```

Comment: Is the ID column set to an identity?  It looks like you are adding that in the INSERT statement, but not your code.  If it isn't you will need to add that before you commit your changes.  It's probably complaining because you are not including the required ID in your EF code.  Try either including the ID in the EF code or setting the ID column to auto-increment as an IDENTITY.

Comment: What is `Database.SetInitializer(new SQLdb());`?

Comment: unrelated pro tip: do not write code in your native language (unless its English).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in your C# Entity Framework code, you are not including a value for ID, which would imply that you have it set to auto-increment as an IDENTITY value.  However, in your `INSERT` statement, you include a value for it, which would not work if you had it set as an IDENTIY value.  To solve your issue, you can do one of two things:

1. **Change your `ID` column to auto-increment.**  This will allow you to keep your C# code as it is, and it should work as expected without supplying a value.  Do this if you don't want to be directly responsible for the value inserted there.
2. **Include a value in your EF code for the `ID` column:**

   ```
   using (var ctx = new BazyDanychContext())
   {
       Osoba tmpTask = new Osoba { ID = IDLbl.Text, Imie = ImieLbl.Text, Nazwisko = NazwiskoLbl.Text, Telefon = TelefonLbl.Text, Adres = AdresLbl.Text, Mail = MailLbl.Text, IloscTransakcji = Int32.Parse(IloscLbl.Text), Typ = TypList.Text };
       ctx.Osoba.Add(tmpTask);
       ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

Comment: We've tried adding ID as you showed above. The result was the same. But thanks for response.

Comment: @MichałFilipowicz is your database column set as an IDENTITY?  Is it expecting a value to be provided?  You might want to confirm the ID of your object before it's inserted and see what it is set to.  Also, it looks like that column allows a `null` value, so that might also explain the difference between your C# and SQL statements.

Comment: However, after dropping and re-adding the ID column, this time setting it as 'identity' it started working. Thanks a lot for your help.